# Cursor Disappearing

Tags: itunes, cursor

Sometimes when I open up a video in iTunes the cursor image disappears.

To bring it back, I've to either double-click or switch to mission control for a quick sec. and come back.

This problem is really annoying; so anyone having something similar or better yet any solutions?

Comment: Is this not intended behavior?  Most people don't want the cursor blocking a video.

Comment: when the video is playing, yes it should disappear as I want it as well. But when I move the cursor around, it should appear back which it doesn't sometimes.

Comment: I believe it does not come back unless you click.  It's quite possible your mouse went to sleep.

Comment: I don't think that's the case around here. Then how come the cursor gets activated by a right-click or Mission Control gesture? I think the problem is with the mouse cursor buffer. I'm pretty sure that it's not sleeping since when this problem occurs, I take the cursor to a corner even if I don't see it. And when I do a right-click or a Mission Control gesture, I see the cursor at that corner.